# Variable that can store multiple types with no shared functionality

Tags: go

I have multiple types and I want to pass around data of those types, like store them in a variable and pass them to functions:

```
type Pizza struct {
    Toppings []string
    Diameter int
}
type Steak struct {
    Weight   float64
    Doneness string
}
type Car struct {
    Speed int
}
type Chair struct {
}

func main() {
    var favoriteFood interface{}

    favoriteFood = Pizza{
        Diameter: 20,
    }

    cook(favoriteFood, Chair{})
}

func cook(food interface{}, vehicle interface{}) {
    fmt.Print("Cooking ")

    if pizza, ok := food.(Pizza); ok {
        fmt.Println("a " + strconv.Itoa(pizza.Diameter) + " cm pizza")
    }
    if steak, ok := food.(Steak); ok {
        fmt.Println("a " + steak.Doneness + " steak")
    }

    if car, ok := vehicle.(Car); ok {
        fmt.Print(" in a car at " + strconv.Itoa(car.Speed) + " km/h")
    }
    if _, ok := vehicle.(Chair); ok {
        fmt.Print(" on a chair")
    }
}
```

[Full example](https://play.golang.org/p/vEfXGKQGLiY)

I would like `cook()` to accept `Pizza` and `Steak` for `food` but not `Car`.

Since interfaces are defined by their methods and my types don't share any common methods, I can't let them "implement" an interface.

I could also introduce an identifying receiver function, like this:

```
type Food interface {
    IsFood() bool
}
func (f *Pizza) IsFood() bool { return true }
func (f *Steak) IsFood() bool { return true }
```

Is that common/idiomatic?

Comment: You should ask why would you want to cook vehicle. It is inedible. Think about your food, if they literally have nothing in common (or at least nothing in common to be cooked) why do they share a same function? It looks very much like a design problem.

Comment: That's the point, I don't want to be able to cook a Vehicle. However, I might want to cook a certain Food in a certain Vehicle: `cook(f Food, v Vehicle)`. (I only added the part about `Vehicle` to preempt the answer "Implement `Cook()` on your `Food`interface.

Comment: I don't understand. Then define a Vehicle interface with a method like `CookAt`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Edited, I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: I don't think my question get answered.

Comment: Well if this identification is based on only attributes of the struct or its type, then consider adding `isFood` and `isVehicle` functions  and call them from `cook`

Comment: @leafbebop What would be the signature of `CookAt()`?

Comment: It can always be `CookAt(v Vehicle)`, `Vehicle` being another interface.

Answer (score 0):

Go provides interfaces to support your requirements. As an example, you can have an interface called `Food`:

```
type Food interface {
    Cook()
}
```

Now let `Pizza` and `Steak` satisfy this interface:

```
func (p *Pizza) Cook() {
    // use Pizza's fields
    // ...
}
```

You can now have a `CookFood` method that can accept both `Pizza` and `Steak`:

```
func CookFood(f Food) {
    // ...
    f.Cook()
    // ...
}
```

You can call this like:

```
func main() {
    var favoriteFood = Pizza{
        Diameter: 20,
    }

    CookFood(favoriteFood)
}
```

Calling `CookFood` with `Car` (which does not implement `Cook` method) would make compiler throw an error, providing proper type safety.

Comment: This is exactly the solution that breaks down as soon as `cook()` needs another such parameter. It seems I didn't make that clear enough, I will edit my question.

Comment: You can always append more methods in your interface. I don't think there is any way to make core design changes without changing the code.

Comment: @AndreKR: Then don't let `Cook()` take additional arguments. Pass those additional arguments to other functions, instead. i.e. `AddToppings()` before calling `Cook()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed your code making use of interface: [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Ux3vXCNl3pS)

The interface part:

```
type Food interface {
    CookedInfo() string 
}

func (p Pizza) CookedInfo() string {
    return "a " + strconv.Itoa(p.Diameter) + " cm pizza"
}

func (s Steak) CookedInfo() string {
    return "a" + s.Doneness + " steak"
}

type Location interface { //chair is hardly a vehicle
    Where() string
}

func (c Chair) Where() string {
    return "on a chair"
}

func (c Car) Where() string {
    return "in a car at " + strconv.Itoa(c.Speed) + " km/h"
}
```

The whole point (well, maybe not whole but very closely) of `interface` is to **hide implentation details**. For example, a `Pizza`'s size, name or other attribute are such details, the function `cook` care not about them. Nor does it care about whether a steak is over-done, nor whether you are cooking a dragon, as a dragon has a method `CookedInfo`. And each food implents its own method to provide info of being cooked, used by `Cook`. That is it. It prevents you to write an infinate list of testing types (which even become impossible when the function is being exported as in a lib) and simplify your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve slightly modified previous example - https://play.golang.org/p/uN1m7pNZbsv

You may try to use embedding and embed interface `Food` into a concrete structures `Pizza` and `Steak` but not car.

```
type Food interface {
    Cook()
}

type Pizza struct {
    Food
    Diameter int
}

func Cook(food Food) {
   ...
}
```

This way only structs matching `Food` will be accepted.

But do not forget Go is duck-typed language, so if you suddenly implement method `Cook` on `Chair` you may [start cooking it](https://play.golang.org/p/9K0ZWMT8sde) )
However it doesn’t embed `Food` explicitly.

Comment: And how would you wirte the `cook` function this way?

Comment: The same as it’s written now - accepting one argument of type `Food`. Pls check links

Comment: I double-checked the link yet in your code, while you accepted a Food interface, you do not use it. I believe that seperating interface and behavior is not a good idea.

Comment: You are quite right - I use it only in function definition `func cook(food Food, location Location)`. So I get type checking and force compiler to allow only `Food`-compatible variables. Try to pass to this function for example `Car`.

Comment: Sure you did. But that makes the `cook` function useless. If you don't define a specified behavior on `cook`(method) why should it be passed into that function? Embedding into struct is not helpful in my opinion: it helps compiling, but missed the point of the interface design. If you need to auctually have the `cook` run as op's would, either you start writing ugly type assertion like op or you define methods on concrete structs. And that seems to me unhelpful.

Comment: In TS case function `(Food).Cook()` can have some meaning. But the code is not bound to this moment. And that’s good.

Comment: I don't think so. You are embedding a Interface into a struct and it has no underlying concrete types which means it will panic if you call its method, unless you auctually set it to some value. But in that sense, it is better to use an embedded concrete type or again define its own method.

Comment: I see two cases: 1.  Just **ignore** the existence of `Cook` method, nobody obliged to call it. This way you obtain simple static check in your code. For free. And as a Topic Starter @AndreyKR wants without implementing those methods.  2. Go deeper and treat it as an **abstract method** of superclass like in Java eg. No problem: implement and use in all “children”. This is more about design (choose simple check or full-fledged support for further development) than language tools. And main feature: Golang allows you to start with primitive checks and later easily redesign to full usage.